# How to get the value of text box using onChange function

Tags: javascript, php

I want to get a value of text box when it's value chenaged. I am using onchange function to get the value of text box when it changed.Here it's give a result but not changed value.It give's a value of the text box before changed value.How can get changed value.

Here is my script:

```
function myFunction(id)
{
    var id=id;
    var quantity = document.getElementById("quantity").value;
    alert(quantity);
}
```

My onchange function:

```
<input type="text" value="<?php echo $res['quantity']; ?>" name="qty" id="quantity"  onChange="myFunction(<?php echo $res['id']; ?>);"/>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you provide a reproducible demo, without all that php?

Comment: `var id = id;` ????????????

Comment: check roytuts.com/submit-form-javascript-onchange/

Answer (score 0):

For `<input>` tag you have `oninput` event, not `onchange`. Your Javascript should look like this:

```
document.querySelector('#quantity').addEventListener('input', myFunction);

function myFunction() {
    // 'this'  refers to the input, because you appended listener to it
    console.log(this.value); //to avoid alert spam...
}
```

Functions gets hoisted so you can use them before they are declared, in case you were wondering.

Another way to add listener (but beware, you can replace or override it if you perform assignment again:

```
document.querySelector('#quantity').oninput = myFunction;
```

And your HTML would look like this:

```
<input type='text' id='quantity' name='qty' value="<?php echo $res['quantity']; ?>">
```

Answer (score 0):

Use OnKeyUp or blur Event so once you enter text and switch to something from that text box you will get  that text use alert to have a check:

```
    <input type="text" onBlur="check(this.value);" />

    Function check(id) {
    alert(id);
    }
```

hope it will help...